# cachedResponseForRequest won't be called after loading the same URL

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, caching, uiwebview, nsurlcache

I subclassed `NSURLCache`, and overwrote `cachedResponseForRequest`, and changed the shared cache to my own cache object, to intercept every url request made by a `UIWebView`. It works perfectly at the first time, when the URL loaded into the `UIWebView`, it intercepts everything (css, jpg, etc). But when I try to load the same URL (eg. index.html), the `cachedResponseForRequest` method won't be called. If then I try with a different URL it works perfectly again.

I tried to modify the request's cachePolicy to every possible values, but nothing helped.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution: after every URL request, you have to release all the UIWebViews, and re-create them before the next request. IMPORTANT: every release should occur before the new allocs.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the best solution to destroy, recreate, reconfigure and reposition all web views.

Comment: Tell this to the Apple guys, it was not my idea to create a cache inside the UIWebView which cannot be explicitly cleared for these reasons. PS. this solution is for IOS4 only